# Software architecture advice for a Sokoban clone

Tags: architecture, godot

I'm building a [Sokoban](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sokoban) clone, and I would like to try to get the architecture right for future extensions. Sokoban is a simple game, where the player has to move boxes around a grid and place them in target locations. The player can move in grid up, down, left or right. Boxes can be moved by pushing them (not by pulling) and only if they have an adjacent free cell where they can be moved.

I'm using the Godot game engine with C#, and I'm using a `TileMap` node to represent the grid, with various nodes for the player, boxes and targets.

The temptation is to create a big GameBoard script attached to the root node of the scene which contains everything for the full game logic, however I'm afraid it will degrade into spaghetti soon, and I would like to add more "special" features like blocking obstacles which are deactivated at some point and more.

What could be a more flexible architecture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a more general answer with no godot specific code but can be easily transfered to it.

First you have to decide for yourself how you want to have the logic done. Do you want to have one central manager/ gameboard script that handles all the logic or are the components itself responsible for logic?

If your components can have logic attached to them, adding new special features like key/ gate blocks, teleports or sliding grounds will be all handled by the component/ tile and their seperate logic.

If you have a central manager, you can still break it down into seperat components like `determinateWin`, `possibleMove`, `doMove`, `updateMap` etc. The more you think beforehand how to break it down, the easier it should be to add more features in the future.

Both approaches can lead to different problems. The big master script might be more prone to spagetti code. The component approach might have side effects when different components are interacting in unexpected ways (While this can be true as well for the master script, the master script should handle all the logic and the board is just used for display vs when the board/ the tiles on the board itself have power to decide what is happening).

One general tip is to just add a lot of commentary to your code that when you add new features in the future, you know for sure what a certain piece of code did or why you did it that way.

Comment: After a bit more of thinking I decided to split the various components while also having a central board. The central board keeps track of the position of boxes and targets by having each box and target adding its position to the board; when the player moves checks if there's a box in the next cell and if so asks to the box if it can move (the box return whether it can or not by checking the adjacent cells).

Comment: There is no right or wrong way. And usually every solution is taking a bit of everything and brings the pieces that are needed together. In the end it is your game and you know the best what is needed, what you want to do in the future and which way feels the most natural for you. Good luck with your game